# Update yammer group from public to private via API

Tags: api, yammer

Is it possible to:

Update yammer group from public to private via API?

I am trying to do something like this:
https://www.yammer.com/networkname/groupID.json?id=groupID&private=true&authenticity_token=token

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is possible. You can read about updating groups [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/yammer/yam/Yammer/Api/Group#update_group-instance_method) (it's documentation 
for Ruby, but parameters works for REST API as well).

I don't understand your link. I think it's not a proper endpoint.

You should send **PUT** request to endpoint **/api/v1/groups.json** with parameters: **group_id** and **privacy** (as written in Ruby documentation).

Hope it helps :)